# How bind properly container's content to host folder?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, devops

I'm tring to bind container's content to host folder, so that i can easy edit it, but for some reason it doesn't work!

here my docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  webserver:
    image: nginx:mainline-alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./config:/etc/nginx/conf.d
```

Please note that this is my folder structure before the docker-compose command:

```sh
-project
--docker-compose.yaml
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What exactly is not working? Note that a bind mount like that is for exposing *host* directories into the *container* (so the content in `./config` will override anything in `/etc/nginx/conf.d`).

Comment: I would like to make the opposite, so that when the container starts, the content of nginx is binded  in my , before empty, defined foldesr, does it make sense?How can i do it?

Comment: @kri-dev: your question is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mounting a folder from the container on the host is not possible.

To achieve what you want consider the following

1. First launch the container without any volumes defined
2. Run `docker cp webserver:/etc/nginx/conf.d/. ./config` to copy the content of `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` to your `config` folder on the host
3. Kill the container and relaunch it with the config folder mounted on `/etc/nginx/conf.d` (like in your original example). This will shadow the nginx config in the container with the one on your local machine
4. When editing the local files it will reflect in the container.

If you want to persist your changes in the image after you are done, create a new Docker image by building the following Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:mainline-alpine
COPY ./config/* /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```